# How to flesh out oil magic as an opposite to water magic?

Tags: magic, balancing-magic-systems

So in the magic system in my world, everyone (who is an occultist or is given permission by the highest being) has access to the **Shi'eram**, also called **Song of Spirits**, which is a well of some sort to draw power from.

There are basically infinite possibilities of applications(harmonies) that one can create and use using the Shi'eram. All applications have an opposite.
For example,
The opposite of **Flamecharm**(creating combustions/burning the air) is **Frostdraw**(freezing the air)
All discovered Harmonies have opposites.

But I've made oil magic (**Oilcry**) the opposite of water magic (**Tidesway**) and I can't figure out how to flesh out oil magic! Especially as a counter to water magic.
My first idea was to make it essential oil magic or whatever, or as ceremonial magic for anointing, and it could also be about using poisons and medicines, but I don't know what the point of it would be if you can't just create oil, which is creating matter and would drain one's soul a LOT.

I can't figure out how to make this type of magic as unique as all the others. What do you think I should do?? Need help!!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: It seems strange that the opposite of oil would be water. Yes, oil & water famously don't mix, but that doesn't mean they are _in direct opposition_. Water is wet, fluid, and a heat sink. Oil is also wet & fluid (albeit more viscous). Oil is also slick, adheres to things, & is (often) flammable. If you added oil simply because you needed an opposite for water (which is how your question makes it sound), I'd replace oil with something else. If you're married to having oil be a kind of magic, I'd choose something else as its opposite, and then use that opposite to guide the definition of oil.

Comment: You say, "I don't know what the point of it would be if you can't just create oil, which... would drain one's soul a LOT." Maybe just bite the bullet and have it be the case that oil magic is very draining. Real life has plenty of disciplines with no "entry-level" tier that's accessible to n00bs. Perhaps oil magic is simply too heavyweight for novices. The (super-)natural word is not like some video game where everything is laid out in nice incremental steps that make success easy. Real things are hard and unforgiving. Dynamite will kill you dead even if it's your first day in Dynamite Class.

Comment: You might also consider that oil magic could allow somebody to transmute other liquids into oil. That wouldn't require creating matter. Really, I suspect you just haven't tried hard enough to use your imagination.

Comment: Questions where the answer depends on the opinion of the answerer, are prohibited on this site. So are questions looking for help brainstorming or generating ideas. You can flesh it out however you want. Instead of asking us to come up with ideas for you, try instead to ask for help resolving some specific impediment to an idea you've come up with working in your world.

Comment: I feel that you are attempting to force an opposite where one doesn't exist. Oil isn't the opposite of water in any way I can imagine. They're incompatible, sure, but that just makes them separate, not opposing. Philosophically, fire has always been the opposition to water. If you want to change that, you have to identify what specific characteristics you are opposing. Fluidity and mutability? Then stone is your opposite. Calm and cool? Then fire is your opposite. Pick your characteristics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oil has many interesting properties: It's a nonpolar liquid which will readily cling and coat most surfaces. It's also organic.

Therefore, oil magic may offer enchantments, buffs and mending spells.

Water will have dispells where it washes away enchantments, both good ones and bad ones, as it does in Heroes of Might and Magic III. However, the cure spells will go to oil magic realm. You can see how this leads to 'holy magic'.

Oil is also known for lubricating properties, hence enchantments of haste may also go to this school. At the same time oil can be very sticky substance, so slow and entanglement enchantments may also go to this school.

Comment: Don't answer questions asking for your opinion, help brainstorming or generating ideas. Such questions are inappropriate for this site and should be flagged for closure. Answering them gives new users an inaccurate understanding of site policy, and can lead to confusion.